# mystery quotes in read-from-file string cannot be removed?

Tags: vb.net, string, file, double-quotes

There are a lot of questions about removing quotes from strings, but none address the issue I'm experiencing. I hope this question will get read over before being marked as a duplicate.

I'm a student and just finished my first class, "intro to computer programming." Now I'm writing a madlib for the sake of learning.

First, the problem is I am reading a string from a text file. Double-quotes appear to be added to the string, but they're quotes I cannot remove. They're like quantum quotes and don't appear until try to measure them.

So I'm trying to remove them using different means. Most recently, I tried the *mid function*.

Here's the code

```
Public Sub printMadlib(ByVal madlibOutput As String)
        Dim cleanOutput As String = ""
        Dim length As Integer = madlibOutput.Count - 2
        Dim start As Integer = madlibOutput.Count - length

        cleanOutput = Mid(madlibOutput, start, length)

        Console.WriteLine(cleanOutput)

       'This is how the string appears in the file 
       'vbCrLf & "Edge of the _adjective1 _adjective2 Sea by The Cure" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "And so we watch the _noun1 come up" & vbCrLf & "from the edge of the _adjective1 _adjective2 sea" & vbCrLf & "and she _verb1 like her _bodypart1's on fire" & vbCrLf & "like she wants to believe in me." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "So I _verb2 put your _bodypart2 in the _noun2" & vbCrLf & "surrender, remember" & vbCrLf & "We'll be here forever" & vbCrLf & "And we'll never say goodbye." & vbCrLf
    End Sub
```

The result I get is "bCrLF" instead of "vbCrLF" plus the remainder. I'm about to gouge my eyes out. How can I remove these quotes that are both there and not there? Any ideas for a newbie?

Thanks!

EDIT: Trying to be more clear: 
The string in the file is this: vbCrLf & "some text" & vbCrLf & "more text"
Output is: vbCrLF & "some text" & vbCrLf & "more text"
Desired output is:

some text

more text

Comment: look into `String.Replace()`  replace the quotes (if they are there - if you are going by VS tooltip windows, it will use quotes to show the type), with an empty string (`""`).

Comment: Are there actual quotes in the file?

Comment: I'm using visual studio to check the string, and it's in quotes. Well I feel dumb now. However, I still have the issue where the output is "vbCrLf & ..." I tried using /n earlier, but that is printed to screen verbatim too.

Comment: @MicroVirus No, there are no quotes in the file. Edit: I mean to say there are no quotes at the beginning and end of the string in the file.

Comment: if there are no quotes in the file, and you did not add them you might just be confused by the VS display.  it will use quotes to indicate the var type

Comment: How robust does the solution need to be? Does it need to handle embedded `'"'` characters? Else, I'd say for the quick and dirty use `String.Replace` to replace each occurrence of `vbCrLf` with a space `' '` and each occurrence of `""""` with an empty string `""`.

Comment: @MicroVirus Thanks! What I really want is for those vbCrLfs to come out as line feeds. I'm guessing I have to chop the string into separate lines and print them individually.

Answer (score 1):

`Mid` won't help you if you have multiple occurrences of quotes as it just extract a portion of a string. Incidentally the reason why it is failing is because you are starting 2 characters from the end of the string.

To remove all occurences of a character from a string use `AString.Replace(charToRemove, "")`

So in your code:

```
cleanOutput = madlibOutput.Replace("""", "")
```

The first parameter `""""` actually means 'one double quote' as it has to be escaped to be placed into a double quoted string.